# Return rows as columns Microsoft Access SQL query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the following query

```
SELECT o.ea_guid as CLASSGUID, o.Object_Type as CLASSTYPE, 
       o.Name, type.Property, type.Value
FROM ((t_object as o
       INNER JOIN t_objectproperties as type
         ON o.Object_ID = type.Object_ID)
```

It returns results as follows

```
Name         Property        Value
Result1      Location        Queens
Result1      Size            King
Result1      Cost            100
Result2      Location        Queens
Result2      Special         Christmas
Result2      Cost            10
```

What i would like is

```
Name        Location        Size         Special          Cost
Result1     Queens          King                          100
Result2     Queens                       Christmas        10
```

How do i build such a query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about a good old Crosstab Query?

```sql
TRANSFORM First([Value]) AS FirstOfValue
SELECT [Name]
FROM
    (
        SELECT o.Name, type.Property, type.Value
        FROM t_object as o
               INNER JOIN t_objectproperties as type
                 ON o.Object_ID = type.Object_ID
    )
GROUP BY [Name]
PIVOT [Property] IN ('Location','Size','Special','Cost')
```

Comment: Is it support by Microsoft Access though?

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey Yes, that is a valid Access crosstab query.

Comment: Sorry am new to crosstab queries but do i have to replace `First([Value])` with something specific?

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey I don't understand your question. Take a look at the documentation [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/make-summary-data-easier-to-read-by-using-a-crosstab-query-HA010229577.aspx) and see if it helps.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. It works like a charm. Is there a way to return values that are a `memo` datatype. At the moment, it returns `<memo>`